# RestSharp OAuth 1.0 DELETE request with Twitter APIs

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, restsharp, http-delete

I'm using RestSharp c# library to delete the existing Twitter welcome message rules according to [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/del/direct_messages/welcome_messages/rules/destroy). Please check the my code below. Rule id is the id of the existing welcome message rule I'd like to delete.

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/welcome_messages/rules/destroy.json?id=" + ruleId);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.DELETE);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_token", myAccessToken);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", myConsumerKey);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(myConsumerKey, myConsumerSecret, myAccessToken, myAccessTokenSecret);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I use a very similar code to create new Twitter welcome message rules using a POST request. And it works as expected. However, the DELETE request above returns an authentication error:

> "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":32,\"message\":\"Could not authenticate
>   you.\"}]}"

I have checked my keys, tokens, and secrets more than 100 times and they work with all the other GET and POST requests. Furthermore, I can successfully execute the above request when I use POSTMAN. Seems like, Twitter rejects the authentication of DELETE requests for some reason.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is this a bug in Restsharp library?

Any help, suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 5 years later - you should have used `OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource` and not `ForAccessToken`